# highlight selected tab

Tags: php, jquery

I have searched but could not find answer to my satisfaction so
I have a header file, which is being included on top of every page and part of the header is a menu with 3 tabs, when user click on tab browser take them to that page (working fine), what i want is, that what ever tab user clicks to be highlighted(diff back color) when that page is loaded.

Here is html :

```
<div id="top-choicebar">
       <ul id="topmenu">
             <li><a href="daily.php" class="ww"  >Daily</a></li>
             <li>< href="weekly.php" class="ww">Weekly</a></li>
             <li>< href="monthly.php" class="ww">Monthly</a></li>
       </ul>

 <div id="event-menu">
```

New to php and jquery ... any help will be greatly appriciated

Comment: areyou loading the pages ajaxly? or are those just simple links that reload the page entirely?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by means of CSS and conditional classes.

```
<a href="weekly.php" class="<?= stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'weekly.php') ? 'selected' : ''?>">Weekly</a>
<a href="monthly.php" class="<?= stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'monthly.php') ? 'selected' : ''?>">Monthly</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using something like this, but it's very rudimentary:

```
<?php if (preg_match("/weekly.php/i", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])) {
    // Tab should be highlighted
    < href="weekly.php" class="ww active">Weekly</a>
} else {
    < href="weekly.php" class="ww">Weekly</a>
}
?>
```

this will add an 'active' class to the link, that you can then style with CSS to change the background colour...

Answer (score 0):

What I've always done in the past is pass a parameter to the class that is building the menu based on what page I'm loading.

So `daily.php` loads up `Header.php` and passes it a variable like `new Header(0)` when Header builds the html, it loops through the links to print them, and on the number that's been passed, it adds a class like `current`.

So if:

Daily == 0
Weekly == 1
Monthly == 2

The header would pick the correct one to apply the class to based on the page that calls it.

Of course, this would only work if your menu links are being stored somewhere besides raw HTML, like in a database or even just an array.

Comment: thx ... header is always same .. could give me hint in iQuery i am not using ajax at all

Answer (score 0):

Have a class setup like `.selected{background-color:red}` That defines the different background color you want to view. Then when you render the page, since you already know which tab it is, you just render the selected tab with that class attached. If you are rendering the tab content through ajax you can just find all tabs with class "selected" and then add the class to the selected tab
$("#topmenu li").live("click", function()
{
    $("#topmenu").find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});